Compilation problem when using nuitka within container environments?
I'm running commands such as 'python setup.py bdist_wheel bdist_nuitka', but I'm consistently faced with a prompt within my container environment, as I'm unable to manually input 'yes'. Is there a way to automatically bypass this prompt?
My Nuitka build worked seamlessly with Python 3.8.3 and Nuitka 0.6.8.1. However, we're currently in the process of Additionally, while experimenting with different Nuitka versions, I encountered the following message. migrating to Python 3.10.
Nuitka: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '2.0.6' on Python '3.10' commercial grade 'not installed'.


Nuitka: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.


Nuitka: Generating source code for C backend compiler.


Nuitka: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.


Nuitka: Running C compilation via Scons.


Nuitka-Scons: Backend C compiler: C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe (gcc.exe 13.2.0).


Nuitka will make use of ccache to speed up repeated compilation.





Is it OK to download and put it in 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Nuitka\Nuitka\Cache\downloads\ccache\v4.6'.





Fully automatic, cached. Proceed and download? [Yes]/No :


Append parameter --assume-yes-for-downloads to your Nuitka command should solve your problem.
